# 3rd physical drive no longer found

Tags: 12.04, hard-drive

Using Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit, I had the Ubuntu 12.04 on one of my two original 320 Gb HD, and a plethora of old backup files on the other. A few years ago, I added a 1 Tb HD and have been saving my recent backups to it using Back in Time.

As of yesterday, the 1 Tb HD does not appear in devices.
I checked the power and data plugs to this drive and they appear normal. Could the drive have suddenly gone dead or is there something else that I should check?

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0002be96

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048  1949333503   974665728   83  Linux
/dev/sda2      1949335550  1953523711     2094081    5  Extended
/dev/sda5      1949335552  1953523711     2094080   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0002e221

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *          63   353703104   176851521   83  Linux
/dev/sdb3       353703934   625137344   135716705+   5  Extended
/dev/sdb5       614020428   625137344     5558458+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb6       353703936   609830911   128063488   83  Linux
/dev/sdb7       609832960   614019071     2093056   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: 2144 MB, 2144337920 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 260 cylinders, total 4188160 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0f1d0188

Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
brooks@brooks-System-Product-Name:~$ Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0002be96

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048  1949333503   974665728   83  Linux
/dev/sda2      1949335550  1953523711     2094081    5  Extended
/dev/sda5      1949335552  1953523711     2094080   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0002e221

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *          63   353703104   176851521   83  Linux
/dev/sdb3       353703934   625137344   135716705+   5  Extended
/dev/sdb5       614020428   625137344     5558458+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb6       353703936   609830911   128063488   83  Linux
/dev/sdb7       609832960   614019071     2093056   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: 2144 MB, 2144337920 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 260 cylinders, total 4188160 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0f1d0188

Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

---

```
$ lsblk
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                     8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─sda1                  8:1    0 929.5G  0 part  /
├─sda2                  8:2    0     1K  0 part  
└─sda5                  8:5    0     2G  0 part  
  └─cryptswap1 (dm-0) 252:0    0     2G  0 crypt [SWAP]
sdb                     8:16   0 298.1G  0 disk  
├─sdb1                  8:17   0 168.7G  0 part  
├─sdb3                  8:19   0     1K  0 part  
├─sdb5                  8:21   0   5.3G  0 part  
├─sdb6                  8:22   0 122.1G  0 part  
└─sdb7                  8:23   0     2G  0 part  
sr0                    11:0    1  1024M  0 rom   
sr1                    11:1    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: Edit your question and include `sudo fdisk -l`, `lsblk`. Also `dmesg`.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that it died.  Sometimes, to help restore your data you could get lucky by placing the HDD in a ziplock back, and leaving it in the freezer for 2-4 hours, and if your lucky, the HDD will live for a few more hours, hopefully, providing you with enough time to recover a decent amount of data